# pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf in old installation directory

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, pg-hba.conf

I have installed the PostgreSQL 9.4 on my MacBook via MacPorts, and I am trying to edit pg_hba.conf, but I don't see it in my current installation. Furthermore, psql is reporting that config_file is in my old 9.3 directory! How should I fix this?

```
$ port select --list postgresql
Available versions for postgresql:
    none
    postgresql93
    postgresql94 (active)

$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1

$ psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'
                 config_file
----------------------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

$ ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data
PG_VERSION      pg_hba.conf     pg_notify       pg_stat_tmp     pg_xlog
base            pg_ident.conf   pg_serial       pg_subtrans     postgresql.conf
global          pg_log          pg_snapshots    pg_tblspc       postmaster.opts
pg_clog         pg_multixact    pg_stat         pg_twophase     postmaster.pid

$ ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
ls: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data: No such file or directory

$ ls /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4
ls: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4: No such file or directory

$ psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW data_directory'
    data_directory
------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data
(1 row)

$ locate pg_hba.conf
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample
/opt/local/share/postgresql93/pg_hba.conf.sample
/opt/local/share/postgresql94/pg_hba.conf.sample

$ ls /opt/local/share/postgresql94
conversion_create.sql  postgres.bki           snowball_create.sql
extension              postgres.description   sql_features.txt
information_schema.sql postgres.shdescription system_views.sql
pg_hba.conf.sample     postgresql.conf.sample timezone
pg_ident.conf.sample   psqlrc.sample          timezonesets
pg_service.conf.sample recovery.conf.sample   tsearch_data
```

Comment: Try `psql -U postgres -c 'select version()'`. This will probably show that you're running a 9.3 server. The `9.4.1` reported by `psql --version`  is the client-side. Presumably `postgresql94` for MacPorts does not contain the server, it's another package.

Comment: Yes you are right, it reported PostgreSQL 9.3.4. But after `port install postgresql94-server` `select version()` still reports 9.3.4. How to proceed?

Comment: A quick websearch does not find it for me, but hopefully MacPorts or someone has documented how to upgrade to a newer major server version. A dump/reload is certainly needed (the data directories are not compatible across major versions)

Answer (score 0):

Until postgres version 9.5 the upgrade procedure was to

1. create a new fresh database cluster using the new version
2. make a full dump of the old cluster
3. read the dump into the new cluster.

the selection of the cluster depends on the PGDATA environment variable.
the version of the cluster software version depends on the PATH environment variable.
Make sure they match your needs. The setting is done in the startup scripts and can be copied for the client.